# Jupyter notebook python3 kernel not connecting on some files only

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel, ipython

I freshly reinstalled anaconda.

When I try to open a new blank file, the kernel connects and no import error occurs.
But when I try to open a bigger file that others can open, the kernel never connects, I tried to launch it via anaconda terminal, and this is the error message I have:

```
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .connect import *
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel/connect.py", line 13, in <module>
    from IPython.core.profiledir import ProfileDir
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 115, in <module>
    from IPython.core import debugger
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/pdb.py", line 76, in <module>
    import code
  File "/Users/pierre/Documents/facultee/DL2/miniProjet/projects/OCEAN/starting_kit/code.py", line 193, in <module>
    featureSelection(D)
  File "/Users/pierre/Documents/facultee/DL2/miniProjet/projects/OCEAN/starting_kit/code.py", line 87, in featureSelection
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(20, 10))
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1209, in subplots
    fig = figure(**fig_kw)
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 545, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 3260, in new_figure_manager
    fig = fig_cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 367, in __init__
    FigureCanvasBase(self)  # Set self.canvas.
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1596, in __init__
    self._fix_ipython_backend2gui()
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1623, in _fix_ipython_backend2gui
    ip = IPython.get_ipython()
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/getipython.py", line 22, in get_ipython
    from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
  File "/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 45, in <module>
    from IPython.core.debugger import Pdb
ImportError: cannot import name 'Pdb' from 'IPython.core.debugger' (/Users/pierre/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py)
```

In a blank new notebook, I can properly import Pdb from IPython.core.debugger, while also importing standard python pdb.

Specs:
   I have this bug on an updated MAC os-x & a Windows 10, the jupyter notebook python 3 kernel worked on my mac until I tried to install a kernel for vsc python code cells.
   I use seaborn as an additional library.

Answer (score 0):

First check if the environment in which it is open is correct (normally when you open a new blank book, the environment in which it opens is the base) and if all the modules of that library are installed.